# Scala-3.3.0: dotty.tools.FatalError: cannot resolve reference to

Tags: akka, akka-stream, scala-3

I'm seeing this error with scala-3.3.0 and akka (or pekko):

```
dotty.tools.FatalError: cannot resolve reference to type akka.stream.scaladsl.type.Source
dotty.tools.FatalError: cannot resolve reference to type org.apache.pekko.stream.scaladsl.type.Source
```

In both cases I see no such reference in any of the sources or dependencies.

To demonstrate the problem, I created a small GitHub repo:
https://github.com/abrighton/scala3-test

The main branch uses pekko and the "akka-version" branch uses akka.
Both use java-17 and scala-3.3.0.

The closest issue I could find that might be related was:
https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16373

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [pekko-http](https://github.com/apache/incubator-pekko-http) as a dependency

> The Pekko HTTP modules implement a full server- and client-side HTTP stack on top of `pekko-actor` and `pekko-stream`.

Which means you need to have also the dependencies [pekko-actor](https://github.com/apache/incubator-pekko) and [pekko-stream](https://pekko.apache.org/docs/pekko/current/stream/index.html) added in the classpath.

Just adding

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.pekko" %% "pekko-stream" % PekkoVersion
```

should fix your problem.

---

Side Note:

Not sure if the docs are incomplete or a hello world for `pekko-http` is hard to find. Checking the [Pekko Modules](https://pekko.apache.org/modules.html), `pekko-stream` is not listed. I couldn't find `g8 template` or something similar.

Just based on the error message you shared

```scala
dotty.tools.FatalError: cannot resolve reference to type akka.stream.scaladsl.type.Source
dotty.tools.FatalError: cannot resolve reference to type org.apache.pekko.stream.scaladsl.type.Source
```

And knowing that `Source` comes from the `stream` module, I took a wild guess and added the `pekko-stream` dependency and the compilation succeed.

---

EDIT:

found a [pekko http quickstart](https://github.com/theiterators/pekko-http-quickstart-scala.g8) template